# Vertically aligning the contents of a ListBox in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store App with a `ListBox` which contains Grids of variable height. I can't get these to align at the top. I've tried every combo of `VerticalAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` I can think of, and they're always centered vertically.

Here's my XAML

```
<Page 
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid Margin="50,50,50,50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" />
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="30,0,0,0"> 
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="bxAddItem" Width="300" Height="28" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="Item text" KeyUp="bxAddItem_KeyUp" GotFocus="bxAddItem_GotFocus" LostFocus="bxAddItem_LostFocus"></TextBox>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" x:Name="comboList" SelectionChanged="comboList_SelectionChanged" Width="100" Height="32">
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="0">No List</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <Button Grid.Column="4" x:Name="btnAddItem" Click="AddItem_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#45000000" Height="34">Add an Item</Button>
            </Grid>


            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="2">
                <ListBox Width="Auto" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ToDoLists}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="Beige">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="ToDoList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
                                            Margin="24,0,0,0" Height="Auto" MinWidth="200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                            BorderBrush="BlueViolet" SelectionChanged="ToDoList_SelectionChanged">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"></TextBlock>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                </ListBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </ScrollViewer>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**EDIT:**

Sheridan's answer does not work for me. There may be something else on the page that's causing the issue.

I've updated the question to include the entire page code.

**EDIT 2:**

This post was incorrectly tagged as WPF when in fact the issue is in a Windows Store app. This code works perfectly in WPF, hence the confusion. However it does NOT work in a Windows Store app

Comment: -1 For not testing your code *before* posting your question.

Comment: If the answer from Sheridan is not correct then clarify.

Comment: I've been away from my machine all day. Whoever down-voted your answer it was obviously someone else who disapproved of your shitty manners. 

And just to clarify it still doesn't work for me. Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/568631/Untitled.png

Comment: @roryok, I can't apologise enough. I accept that you didn't down vote me and I apologise for jumping to the wrong conclusion... that must have been really annoying. However, my point about your code remains. I've just re-tested all your code including your new code and it still works just fine. The only difference that I can see is that I used a `Window` and you're using a `Page`. It's very strange... if you copy *your* code into `MainWindow.xaml` in a new WPF application, then you'll also see that it works just fine. There *must* be something else in play that you haven't added here.

Comment: Please follow the steps in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page from the Help Center to come up with a complete but concise code example that still demonstrates your problem and we can all look again.

Comment: @Sheridan apology accepted. This is a Windows Store app, I did mention that at the beginning but I see now that I accidentally tagged it with `WPF` instead of `Windows-Store-Apps`. My bad. I've tested this and it does work just fine in WPF, but it's not correctly aligned in Windows-Store / Metro / Modern UI / WinRT / Whatever-the-hell-I'm-supposed-to-call-it

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it... unfortunately, I don't have Windows 8, so I can't find a solution for you. I've also removed my original down vote now that your question is clearer after your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the ItemContainerStyle to VerticalAlignment="Top"

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
        </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```